# SharePoint Server 2010 and Biztalk Server on the same server or on two seperate server

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, installation, prerequisites

I want to install BizTalk Server on the server that installed SharePoint Server.

and want to know SharePoint is pre-requirement for Biztalk or not?

and installation of biztalk has any difference when SharePoint installed on another server or install on server that Biztalk there?( in the same dedicated server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [BizTalk Server software requirements](http://www.microsoft.com/biztalk/en/us/system-requirements.aspx):

> The Windows SharePoint Services adapter Web service requires SharePoint Server 2010, SharePoint Foundation 2010, Windows SharePoint Services 3.0 with Service Pack 1, or Microsoft Office SharePoint Server 2007.

So, if you want to use the SharePoint adapter for BizTalk, then yes - your BizTalk server will have to be on a server that is part of your SP Farm.

If you're not interested in that feature, then you can install BizTalk on a separate server.